# Scrapy: how to get links to users?

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I'm trying to get links to [group members](https://www.meetup.com/ru-RU/Connect-IT-Meetup-in-Chisinau/members/):

```
response.css('.text--ellipsisOneLine::attr(href)').getall()
```

Why isn't this working?

html:

```html
<div class="flex flex--row flex--noGutters flex--alignCenter">
  <div class="flex-item _memberItem-module_name__BSx8i">
    <a href="/ru-RU/Connect-IT-Meetup-in-Chisinau/members/280162178/profile/?returnPage=1">
      <h4 class="text--bold text--ellipsisOneLine">Liviu Cernei</h4>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector isn't working because you are looking for a attribute (`href`) that this element doesn't have.

```
response.css('.text--ellipsisOneLine::attr(href)').getall()
```

This selector is searching for `href` inside elements of class `text--ellipsisOneLine`. In your HTML snippet that class matches only with this:

```
 <h4 class="text--bold text--ellipsisOneLine">Liviu Cernei</h4>
```

As you can see, there is no `href` attribute. Now, if you want the **text** between this `h4` element you need to use `::text` pseudo-element.

```
response.css('.text--ellipsisOneLine::text').getall()
```

Read more [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extensions-to-css-selectors).

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this isn't scrapy, but personally for web scraping I use the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module and [BeautifulSoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), and the following code snippet will get you a list of users with the aforementioned modules:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.meetup.com/ru-RU/Connect-IT-Meetup-in-Chisinau/members/')

if response.status_code == 200:
    html_doc = response.text
    html_source = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

    users = html_source.findAll('h4')
    for user in users:
        print(user.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
response.css('.member-item .flex--alignCenter a::attr(href)').getall()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.